# How can I use merge so that I have data for all times?

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to change a data into which all entities have value for all possible times(months). Here's what I'm trying;

```
Class  Value  month
  A      10     1
  A      12     3
  A      9      12
  B      11     1
  B      10     8
```

From the data above, I want to get the following data;

```
Class  Value  month
  A      10     1
  A      NA     2
  A      12     3
  A      NA     4
        ....
  A      9      12
  B      11     1
  B      NA     2
        ....
  B      10     8
  B      NA     9
        ....
  B      NA     12
```

So I want to have all possible cells with through month from 1 to 12;
How can I do this? I'm right now trying it with merge function, but appreciate any other ways to approach.

Comment: Try `expand.grid(Class = unique(df$Class), month = min(df$month):max(df$month))`, then merge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   complete(Class, month = min(month):max(month)) %>% 
   select_(.dots = names(df1)) %>%  #if we need to be in the same column order
   as.data.frame() #if needed to convert to 'data.frame'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It is a fancy function for me to know. Well I have some questions though;
1. why put class at the first of 'complete' function? I mean, what does it work and why not 'amount' to be used instead?
2. does select_ work as same as select in dplyr package? and why do we use .dots?

Comment: @KyooSungSo  In that case, there will be 'month' for each unique 'Value' giving 48 rows instead of 24.  yes, the `select_` is from `dplyr`.  Here, we are using `NSE` instead of saying `select(Class, Value, month)`

Answer (score 3):

In base R using `merge` (where `df` is your data):

```
res <- data.frame(Class=rep(levels(df$Class), each=12), value=NA, month=1:12)
merge(df, res, by = c("Class", "month"), all.y = TRUE)[,c(1,3,2)]

   # Class Value month
# 1      A    10     1
# 2      A    NA     2
# 3      A    12     3
# 4      A    NA     4
# 5      A    NA     5
# 6      A    NA     6
# 7      A    NA     7
# 8      A    NA     8
# 9      A    NA     9
# 10     A    NA    10
# 11     A    NA    11
# 12     A     9    12
# 13     B    11     1
# 14     B    NA     2
# 15     B    NA     3
# 16     B    NA     4
# 17     B    NA     5
# 18     B    NA     6
# 19     B    NA     7
# 20     B    10     8
# 21     B    NA     9
# 22     B    NA    10
# 23     B    NA    11
# 24     B    NA    12
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(Class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Value = c(10L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 10L), month = c(1L, 
3L, 12L, 1L, 8L)), .Names = c("Class", "Value", "month"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanx. Great to know by option can be used with a vector!

Answer (score 1):

To add to @akrun's answer, if you want to replace the NA values with 0, you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
complete(Class, month = min(month):max(month)) %>%
mutate(Value = ifelse(is.na(Value),0,Value))
```